# Should I return the cookie in every web response?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

When a user login in my website, it returns a cookie with two hours expire. The cookie is not returned in following calls, so after two hours the cookie expires even when the user is still using the website, and then redirected to the login page.

So I think I know the solution, but is it a good practice return the cookie with the "expire" updated in every call?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a huge deal to set a session cookie in every server response, especially since the client is already sending it to the server in every request.

However, you can do better than that. If the client comes in with a cookie that's bound to expire, say, less than 1 hour and 50 minutes from now, you can send them a new cookie that's set to a new, 2-hour expiration date. You can easily keep track when a client cookie is set (and is therefore bound to expire) in your session handling code.

Comment: Of course, that presumes that all users come back within that 10 minute window regularly. Hitting the page at 1hr49, then coming back again 12 minutes later means bye-bye cookie. Bandwidth overhead is negligible for a simple cookie, so better be safe and send it with each request.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it's T-10 minutes, or T-1 or T-0.1. I just don't think unnecessarily sending things to the client, and making it work by updating its cookie with every request is good design, no matter how small the overhead is.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to *why not?* It solves the timeout problem, and has no drawbacks.
The only side effect is the additional bandwidth necessary to transfer the cookie, but this is completely negligible. If you *do* care about that bandwidth, only resend the cookie every *n* minutes.